# expansiveness imply "relaxed monotonicity"?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space and let $T:H\rightarrow H$ be a map. If there exists a constant $h>0$ such that 
$$\|Tx-Ty\|\geq h\|x-y\|,  \quad  \forall x,y\in H,$$
then we say $T$ is $h$-expansive. Instances: the identity,  the isometry on $H$  and the shift operator on $l^2$.

We say $T$ is strongly  monotone if there is a constant $s>0$ such that 
$$\langle Tx-Ty, x-y\rangle\geq s \|x-y\|^2, \quad \forall x,y\in H.$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, it is easily seen that a strongly monotone operator is expansive. Prove or disprove the following statement: 
Suppose $T$ is an $h$-expansive map on $H$ but not monotone (monotone means $\langle Tx-Ty, x-y\rangle\geq 0, \forall x,y\in H$). Then there is no $c\in(0,h)$ such that it is relaxed monotone, i.e., 
$$\langle Tx-Ty, x-y\rangle\geq -c \|x-y\|^2,  \quad \forall x,y\in H. \tag{2}$$
Typically, (2) is usually true with $c=h$, as a later comment shows. Here we ask $c$ is positive and is strictly less than $h$.

Comment: Here, of course, we should modify " strongly monotone" as "monotone", which means 
$$\langle Tx-Ty, x-y\rangle\geq 0, \forall x,y\in H.$$ Otherwise, (2) is trivial. Thanks!

Comment: Is $T$ a bounded linear operator or just any map?

Comment: $T$ is not necessarily linear, it is just a map acting on $H$, expansive but not monotone. If you can find a linear bounded operator to disprove the question, then it is very OK. I personally thought this is a hard problem.

Comment: Define  $T$ on $l^2$ by $Tx=\sigma x$,  where $\sigma (x_1,x_2,\cdots)=(0,x_1,x_2,\cdots)$. Then it follows readily that  $\|Tx\|= \|x\|$ for all $x\in l^2$ and  by the Cauchy-Schwarz  inequality,$\langle Tx, x\rangle\geq-\|x\|^2$,$\forall x=(x_n)\in l^2$. This shows that (2) is true with $c=h=1$. For this expansive mapping, we now show that there is no $c<1$ such that (2) is true.  Indeed, for $c\leq 0$, let $x=(1,-1,0,0,\cdots)$;  for $0<c<1$, choose $\epsilon>0$ so that $c+\epsilon<1$ and then let $x=\{(-1)^{n-1}(c+\epsilon)^n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. Then $\langle Tx, x\rangle<-c\|x\|^2$.